# I need a Dynamic News Bar Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tel me where I can find a script for a horizental dynamic news bar.

what I mean in dynamic is that I can feed the news into the news bar using xml file or mySQL database or something like this.

I searched for such thing in the internet and found some news bars but there aren't dynamic

Nicest Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/BBCnewsTicker